# How to install private python packages in the dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile

I have a private repo where i have a python package. I have included the package inside my requirements.txt file. When i am trying to build the docker image. I am getting the following error

```
#14 246.0 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connecction.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe307604520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve')': //pypi-production.vogorental.com/py-commons/
#14 246.1 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py-commons==3.8.4 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.2)
#14 246.1 ERROR: No matching distribution found for py-commons==3.8.4
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental

# The above comment is not to be deleted, its necessary. We are using an experimental feature and above line is important to enable that
# please refer to this, https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066 to know more about this
# before building docker image using this dockerfile, please do export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1

FROM python:3.10-alpine

# This unsets the buffering of the stdout data(PS- I don't know what it does, everybody recommended it so I added it)
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

ARG PYPI_USERNAME
ARG PYPI_PASSWORD
ARG PYPI_URL

ENV PYPI_USERNAME=$PYPI_USERNAME
ENV PYPI_PASSWORD=$PYPI_PASSWORD
ENV PYPI_URL=$PYPI_URL


# copying the code
COPY requirements /temp/requirements
COPY api /temp/api
COPY pytest.ini pyproject.toml /temp/

# setting the work directory
WORKDIR /temp/api/


# installing essential packages for building and running packages
# the packages needed for build are later removed while the packages
# needed for running are kept

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install git+ssh://git@github.com:vogolabs/py-commons.git


RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    ca-certificates gcc build-base alpine-sdk postgresql-dev linux-headers musl-dev \
    libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev git \
    && pip install -r ../requirements/requirements.txt --extra-index-url http://${PYPI_USERNAME}:${PYPI_PASSWORD}@${PYPI_URL} --trusted-host ${PYPI_URL} \
    && apk --update --upgrade add gcc musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libffi-dev build-base pango ttf-liberation \
    && find /usr/local \
        \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
        -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
        -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /usr/local \
                | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
                | sort -u \
                | xargs -r apk info --installed \
                | sort -u \
    )" \
    && apk add --virtual .rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && rm -rf src/py-commons/.git/

## this command will run on container creation
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "start.sh"]
```

The pip trying to access the global package as opposed to the private repo. How to redirect it to use my private repo

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you how I am using my private package in my project>

```
FROM python:3.10.6-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./downloads /app/downloads
COPY ./my_private_package /app/my_private_package
COPY ./app.py /app/app.py
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-deps --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 
#PORT
EXPOSE 8080
# configure the container to run in an executed manner
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

So you can directly copy your code to docker imgage and import it as package like

```
from my_private_package import calculate_temprature
```